# Como setar valor padrão em um form através do javascript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de setar um valor padrão em um determinado campo de um formulário através de javascript. Vamos supor que o id do campo seja #codigo.

Comment: Por favor, para melhor te ajudar, por favor coloca o seu código html aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode chamar uma tag *script* no seu html;

```
<script>
    (function(){
        document.getElementById('idDoCampo').value = 'Valor Padrão';
    })();
</script>
```

isso funcionará para tags *input* do tipo *text*.

Ou simplesmente:

```
<input type="text" id="idDoCampo" value="Valor Padrão"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
// JS Puro
document.getElementById('codigo').value = "Teste"

// jQuery
$('#codigo').val('Teste 2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="codigo" name="codigo" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="codigo" >
<script>
document.getElementById("codigo").value = "Meu código";
</script>
```

Ele pega o elemento utilizando o 'getElementById' e seta o seu 'value'.

[Resultado](https://jsfiddle.net/)